# How to pass ImageMagick parameters to PHP Imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

ImageMagick is using [dominantcolor](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/dominantcolor/index.php) to grab colors of an image and it is using some parameters like `mode` for  excluding colors like white or black from colors and also `numcolors` to limit the number of getting colors.

> USAGE: dominantcolor [-m mode] [-n numcolors] [-e excludecolor] [-f
>   fuzzval] [-p print] [-s swatches] infile

How can I do the same using PHP Imagick? For example in following image, how can I get the results like 1 and 2?

[image]

Comment: Please contact me about your usage of my dominant color script. My email address is on my home page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php or at the top of my script.

Comment: @fmw42: if you have a private conversation that results in an answer, would you come back to write an answer that other readers might find useful?

Comment: `@halfer`. Yes, if it makes any sense. I am trying to understand what the actual issue is in a private email conversation with the OP. However, if you have any questions about my scripts, feel free to contact me directly.